# Form not showing up using Sitecore Experience Accelerator

Tags: wffm, sxa

I'm trying to insert a form using the "Form Wrapper" rendering of Sitecore Experience Accelerator.

So I installed WFFM, created a form, inserted a form wrapper in a page within Site Experience Accelerator and I associated my form as associated content but nothing shows up. The area stays empty.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

**Forms Wrapper** rendering is nothing more than a wrapper for **WFFM**. It just needs to display a placeholder where you normally put your forms (this done this way to provide additional styling abilities for forms).

### How to add a WFFM form with SXA

This is how you should add **Web Forms for Marketers Forms** with **Sitecore Experience Accelerator**

1. Open your page
2. Add **Forms Wrapper** rendering `Forms->Forms Wrapper` (now you should see additional section in Toolbox called **WEB FORMS FOR MARKETERS**)
   [image]
3. Drag **Mvc Form** (`WEB FORMS FOR MARKETERS->Mvc Form`) rendering inside **Forms Wrapper**  (notice placeholder path on the right side of the screenshot)
   [image]
4. Starting from this step everything is the same as in vanilla **WFFM**. So just create a blank form or insert existing one.

[image]

After I selected one of the existing forms (Demo form) here is what I see:

[image]

Comment: It works !

Thank you very much.

Do you know were I can get more documentation on each component ?

Regards,
Aloys

Comment: Great. I am afraid you can't get it right now. It is being prepared and should appear in the near future.